# Can an app in beta external testing be updated?

Tags: ios, testflight

Is it possible to upload a new build to iTunes connect and update an app that is currently being tested by external beta testers without disrupting their testing? I'm worried that updating the app will require me to remove the previous version of the app they have on their device, deleting their local data. The apple documentation is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already witnessed this situation in my project. Say, you have testflight app ver 1.0 and testers are testing it and then you release another ver 1.1. Your existing testers who are testing 1.0 will not be disrupted. Testflight application will show that update is available for ver 1.1 and untill you click update button, it will not affect.